# COALESCE error using withing a bracket

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
select 
tele_plan.id as value,
tele_plan.plan_name as label,
tele_plan.plan_cost as c,
tele_plan.plan_details as d,
COALESCE ( tele_plan.plan_cost - sum(tele_payment_items.amount) as  balance ,0) from `tele_plan_select` 
    inner join `tele_plan` on `tele_plan`.`id` = `tele_plan_select`.`teleplan_id`
    left join `tele_payment_defs` on `tele_payment_defs`.`telereg_id` = `tele_plan_select`.`telereg_id` 
    left join `tele_payment_items` on `tele_payment_items`.`telepaymentdefs_id` = `tele_payment_defs`.`id` 
    and
    `tele_payment_items`.`teleplan_id` = `tele_plan`.`id` 
    where `tele_plan_select`.`telereg_id` = 9
    group by `tele_plan`.`id`
```

I am using laravel framework here. I guess the problem here is with the `COALESCE`. I'm trying to find the balance by subtracting two column values. If there is nothing return as `balance` it should be set to `0`, this is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give us **error message** please. It will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `COALESCE` usage is wrong. Change it like

```
COALESCE (tele_plan.plan_cost, 0) - COALESCE(SUM(tele_payment_items.amount), 0) as  balance
```